# How do I restrict the activities of Satanic forces around the teaching of the Word Of God?

Tags: satan

I point you to the 'Parable of the Sower' in three of the Gospels and to 2 Corinthians 4:4. These scriptures make it clear to us that, whenever the Word Of God is preached or taught, Satan gets involved in the following ways:

1. He will immediately steal the seed of the Word if the receiving heart is 'hard ground'.
2. He will bring persecution and affliction for the Word's sake if the receiving heart is 'stony ground'.
3. He blinds the minds of unbelievers, lest the light of the Glorious Gospel should shine unto them. (2 Corinthians 4:4)

It is my belief that a Christian can 'bind Satan' in these teaching situations when the Christian acts in the Name of Jesus and that Satan must then desist in his manoeuvres.

My question is, "Can a Christian 'bind Satan' in the Name of Jesus in a prayer that is recorded in the video lesson that can be played to different audiences at different times and all over the world?"

**or**

Must the Christian be present at the time that the teaching is taking place, in order to be able to 'bind Satan' in this situation in the Name of Jesus?

Comment: Welcome to the Christianity Stack Exchange site.  May I remind you that questions on what the Bible says about a subject must be directed to a specific doctrine/tradition, and  should not encourage opinion-based answers.  Are you seeking answers from Catholics or Protestants?  If so, then please use the Tags to let us know.

Comment: Which denomination teaches that Christians can bind Satan? It would be best to explicitly name and direct this question towards them so that they can explain in detail.

Comment: You notice how Jesus is telling his disciples in this Parable that because of this, they should bind the enemy beforehand? Me neither.

Comment: "*It is my belief that a Christian can …*". So, this question is asking what we know about *your* personally devised religion? Aren't you the best person to be able to answer it? ¶ For a reasonable answer, please give a citation of some other specific denomination that holds this belief.

Answer (score 5):

The Bible tells us that Christians are engaged in spiritual warfare against satanic forces. Ephesians 6:10–12 says:

> Finally, be strong in the Lord and in his mighty power. Put on the full armour of God so that you can take your stand against the devil’s schemes. For our struggle is not against flesh and blood, but against the rulers, against the authorities, against the powers of this dark world and against the spiritual forces of evil in the heavenly realms.

Jesus said “No one can enter a strong man’s house without first tying him up. Then he can plunder the strong man’s house” (Mark 3:27). In this parable, Jesus refers to Satan as the “strong man” and to Himself as the One who enters the house and plunders the place.

Some Christians, usually in the Charismatic or Pentecostal movements, apply Jesus’ parable to the spiritual warfare that believers must wage. They teach that Christians are the ones who must “bind the strong man” in their lives or in their cities and then win the victory in Jesus’ name.  Never does Jesus instruct us to “bind the strong man” or tell us how to do it.  Jesus alone is stronger than “the strong man” who is Satan. He is the only One who can bind the strong man and rescue us from his clutches.  No human can bind Satan.

You ask, "Can a Christian 'bind Satan' in the Name of Jesus in a prayer that is recorded in the video lesson that can be played to different audiences at different times and all over the world?" Or, must the Christian be present at the time that the teaching is taking place, in order to be able to 'bind Satan' in this situation in the Name of Jesus?

I have no idea what you mean by that.  All I would say is that the name of Jesus is not a magic incantation that causes demons to flee from before us. The seven sons of Sceva are an example of what can happen when people presume an authority they have not been given (Acts 19:13–16). Even Michael the archangel did not rebuke Satan in his own power but said, “The Lord rebuke you!” (Jude 1:9).

We rely on God’s power, not our own. We put on the whole armour of God. We draw on the power of Scripture—the Word of God is the Spirit’s sword. We pray in perseverance and holiness, making our appeal to God. We stand firm (Ephesians 6:13–14); we submit to God; we resist the devil’s work (James 4:7).

If there is any binding to be done, leave it up to God.

Comment: Up-voted +1. The modern idea of 'binding the devil' is quite ludicrous. And dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

**Presence?** Perhaps your query can be answered by recalling that Jesus "spoke the word" of healing while He was not in the presence of the sick servant...and the servant revived!

People were healed by "handkerchiefs" sent to the sick from the Apostles, recorded in the book of Acts.

It is not proper to put God in a box. Prophecies can even be spoken about people or incidents miles away, and ring true. But of course, "the healing Touch" is the norm in Christian ministry. Laying hands on the sick, or casting out demons, is most often done in the presence of the afflicted, in the New Testament.

There were no electronic devices in the first century, so there is no definitive statement concerning your question. But there is no law against stepping out in faith and trying to accomplish the "binding of Satan."  If **prayer** can accomplish miracles over the distance of miles, **binding** should also be of no herculean task for the Holy Spirit, even if it is through an anointed prayer that is recorded.

As an aside, there are many testimonies of people getting saved, and of being healed, when watching Christian television programming! The prayer of the minister, recorded for television, was effectual. And the programming continues currently.